# Could not group by list item in javascript object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a javascript object as below and i am trying to group by item.

```
 rfinOu=[
       { "pid": 34, "ava": 30 },
       { "pid": 45, "ava": 30 },
       { "pid": 32, "ava": 60 }
      ]
```

tried:

```
var res = {};
var avapro= d3.nest()
.key(function (d) { return d.ava; })
.rollup(function (v) { return v.length })
//rollup(function (v) { return { count: v.length, pid: d3.sum(v, function (d) { return d.pid; }) }; })
 .entries(rfinOu);
 res = JSON.stringify(avapro);
```

I would like have output after grouped by items like below. but i am not able to..please help.

```
finOu=[
       { "ava": 30, "count":2, "Pids":{"pid":34,"pid":45}},
       { "ava": 60, "count":1, "Pids":{"pid":32}}
                 ]
```

Comment: So you'll want to be creating a new object, with different values, rather than grouping these existing objects together.

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: You say that you are not able to. Show us the code you've attempted so far and perhaps we can give you some help rather than code the whole thing for you.

Comment: You can't have an object with the same property twice: var obj = {"pid" : 34, "pid" : 45}. If you try to access to obj.pid what will be the desired value? If you make an array will be better: "Pids" : [34, 45]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. pids for array also fin. i have added the code which i tried.

Comment: I've corrected a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative.

```
var out = rfinOu.reduce(function (p, c) {
  var key = c.ava;
  p[key] = p[key] || { count: 0, pids: [] };
  p[key].count++;
  p[key].pids.push(c.pid);
  return p;
}, {});
```

This will get you an object with `ava` keys:

```
{
  "30": { "count": 2, "pids": [ 34, 45 ] },
  "60": { "count": 1, "pids": [ 32 ] },
}
```

To get that into an array of objects like the one in your example, just loop over the object keys.

```
var arr = Object.keys(out).map(function(el) {
  return {
    ava: el, count: out[el].count,
    pids: out[el].pids
  }
});
```

To get the following output:

```
[
  { "ava": "30", "count": 2, "pids": [ 34, 45 ] },
  { "ava": "60", "count": 1, "pids": [ 32 ] },
]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/h00q0b0u/)

Comment: Thank you, i will check all the solution. thanks lot...added knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example code with a Pids Array instead an Object:

```
var rfinOu=[
  { "pid": 34, "ava": 30 },
  { "pid": 45, "ava": 30 },
  { "pid": 32, "ava": 60 }
];

var final = [];
var indexes = {};
var position;

rfinOu.forEach(function(item){

  if( indexes.hasOwnProperty(item.ava) ){

    final[indexes[item.ava]].count++;
    final[indexes[item.ava]].Pids.push(item.pid);

  }else{

    position = final.length;

    indexes[item.ava] = position;

    final[position] = {ava: item.ava, count: 1};
    final[position].Pids = [item.pid]; 

  }

});

console.log(final);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/wmub2fo8/)