# Convert a javascript array of multiple similar objects into a smaller array with repeated values as a sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this where employeeIds can show up multiple times with different codes.

```
employees: [
      {
        employeeId: '2',
        code: 64897
      },
      {
        employeeId: '4'
        code: 64897
      },
      {
        employeeId: '1',
        code: 64897
      },
      {
        employeeId: '4',
        code: 67986
      },
      {
        employeeId: '1',
        code: 67986
      }]
```

What is the best way to turn this into an array where employeeIds show up once but have an array of all their codes from the initial data like this?

```
employees: [
{
    employeeId: '2',
    codes: [64897]
},
{
    employeeId: '1',
    codes: [64897, 67986]
},
{
    employeeId: '4',
    codes: [64897, 67986]
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not group by list item in javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290848/could-not-group-by-list-item-in-javascript-object)

Comment: There are more JS questions basically asking the same - try looking for *javascript+group+by*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reduced the `employees` array into a `Map` where the key of the Map is the `employeeId` and the value is an array of employee codes.
2. Created an array out that `Map` using `Array.from()`.

Check the code snippet below:

```js
const employees = [
  { employeeId: '2', code: 64897 },
  { employeeId: '4', code: 64897 },
  { employeeId: '1', code: 64897 },
  { employeeId: '4', code: 67986 },
  { employeeId: '1', code: 67986 },
];

const merged = Array.from(
  employees.reduce(
    (res, { employeeId, code }) => (
      res.has(employeeId)
        ? res.get(employeeId).push(code)
        : res.set(employeeId, [code]),
      res
    ),
    new Map()
  ),
  ([employeeId, code]) => ({ employeeId, code })
);

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken here, juggling types between a Map and an Array of objects here will actually hinder the performance of the overall function. It may worth running a benchmark test.

Comment: You can try running a benchmark, it would be **considerably** better than searching in an array using `.find()`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good place to use `reduce()`. Essentially, we can loop through the array of objects and reduce it to an array of the consolidated employee objects. This should work:

```js
let employees = [
    {
        employeeId: '2',
        code: 64897
    }, {
        employeeId: '4',
        code: 64897
    }, {
        employeeId: '1',
        code: 64897
    }, {
        employeeId: '4',
        code: 67986
    }, {
        employeeId: '1',
        code: 67986
    }
];

employees = employees.reduce((a,c) => (a.find(e => e.employeeId === c.employeeId) ? a.find(e => e.employeeId === c.employeeId).codes.push(c.code) : a.push({ employeeId: c.employeeId, codes: [c.code] }), a), []);

console.log(employees);
```

More information on reduce here ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)). It's still the one array prototype function I'm struggling to master, but it's very powerful.

Comment: This is not quite performant if the employees array is of considerable size.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee would you mind elaborating? Comparing both our functions, I believe mine to be more performant. They're very similar, but your `has` takes longer to run than by find, and your solution deals with type conversion, juggling between a Map object and an Array type.

Comment: I don't think finding in an array is more performant that finding in a Map. That is what Maps are meant for.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce with a `Map` and create new object from the entries of the map.

```js
const
    employees = [{ employeeId: '2', code: 64897 }, { employeeId: '4', code: 64897 }, { employeeId: '1', code: 64897 }, { employeeId: '4', code: 67986 }, { employeeId: '1', code: 67986 }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        employees.reduce((m, { employeeId, code }) =>
            m.set(employeeId, [...(m.get(employeeId) || []), code]), new Map),
        ([employeeId, code]) => ({ employeeId, code })
    );

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't spreading the array again and again `...(m.get(employeeId)` make it an `O(N*N)` solution?